# How to create variable and update when condition is met in Shopify Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to create a global boolean variable and use it to check if a condition is met. If the condition is met perform a certain action and set to true so that the next time the action is not performed.

Here is the code I was trying to use, currently it looks like the global variable is not a affected and its always set to true and the action always takes place.

Thank you in advance! And any recommendations on how to dry this will be appreciated.

```
{% assign firstFound = false %}

{% if product.metafields.pdm.product-details %}
    {% if firstFound == false %} {% assign firstFound = true %} {% endif %}
    <li><button type="button" class="reset {% if firstFound == true %}active{% endif %}" data-target="details">Product Details</button></li>
{% endif %}

{% if settings.about_diamonds %}
    {% if firstFound == false %} {% assign firstFound = true %} {% endif %}
    <li><button type="button" class="reset {% if firstFound == true %}active{% endif %}" data-target="diamonds">About Our Diamonds</button></li>
{% endif %}

{% if settings.shipping_returns %}
    {% if firstFound == false %} {% assign firstFound = true %} {% endif %}
    <li><button type="button" class="reset {% if firstFound == true %}active{% endif %}" data-target="shipping">Shipping and Returns</button></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If the variable is never defined then it will never give you true / false. check for variable is exist or not 

below might help 

https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/89

Comment: @BhargavKaklotara my mistake I missed a line when I copied it over, I am defining the variable before everything else. I updated the code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your code is working as it should. You're setting the `firstFound` variable to `true` so the `active` class is assigned to all your buttons. If you want to assign the class only to the first displayed button, you need to change your code to something like that:

```
{% assign firstFound = false %}

{% if product.metafields.pdm.product-details %}
    <li><button type="button" class="reset{% unless firstFound %}{% assign firstFound = true %} active{% endunless %}" data-target="details">Product Details</button></li>
{% endif %}

{% if settings.about_diamonds %}
    <li><button type="button" class="reset{% unless firstFound %}{% assign firstFound = true %} active{% endunless %}" data-target="diamonds">About Our Diamonds</button></li>
{% endif %}

{% if settings.shipping_returns %}
    <li><button type="button" class="reset{% unless firstFound %}{% assign firstFound = true %} active{% endunless %}" data-target="shipping">Shipping and Returns</button></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: OMG I can't believe I missed that.. I was checking for false on every iteration but then checking for true on the action. Thank you!